# Apache traffic redirection with proxypass error

Tags: reverse-proxy, rewrite, apache2, proxypass

Please I need some help with Apache 2.4.18. This is the third day fighting with this problem.

**Architecture**

- www.myserver.com: front server for traffic redirection
- internal server with local ip 192.168.0.10 that contains 2 folders with one web app each one

  - 192.168.0.10/app01
  - 192.168.0.10/app02

I want to access these web apps through their subdomains

- app01.myserver.com and
- app02.myserver.com

This is my virtualhost configuration file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName app01.myserver.com
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.10/app01
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.10/app01
</VirtualHost>
```

It's working but partially: traffic is being redirected but I'm having problems with links.

**Problem**

After login on *app01.myserver.com* the browser redirect to *app01.myserver.com/dashboard*, some links options on the app menu redirect to their respective modules but:

- when I click *app01.myserver.com/profile* I'm redirected to *app01.myserver.com/profile*
- then I'm redirected to *app01.myserver.com/app01/profile*

And it correctly gives me a 404 error because "*app01/profile*" doesn't exist.

I think I need a rewrite rule or the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse aren't right. Any help it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/app01/(.*)  http://app01.myserver.com/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/app02/(.*)  http://app02.myserver.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: FTW!!!!! It works like a charm @Rainer! :D No more headache thanks!!!!!!